# knitr: getting a parse_all error in R when converting Rmd file into HTML

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am getting below Parsing error each time I use Knit Html in R for converting my Rmd files into HTML:

> Error in parse_all(input, filename, stop_on_error != 2L) :    unused
>   argument (stop_on_error != 2) Calls:  ... call_block ->
>   block_exec -> in_dir -> evaluate -> parse_all

Execution halted

Same result is obtained when using knitr or knitr:knit2html from the  command line. Error did not exist before (I have already used Knit HTML for many .Rmd reports) but appeared when I used knit2html from the cmd for the first time. The compilation is only working where there are no R code chunks in the .Rmd file or when the chunks are empty. I work under windows 7, R version: 3.2.3, R studio version: 0.99.902.  Below is the only R code chunk in the test.Rmd file that I am using for testing:

````
```{r}
i <- 0
i < i + 3
i
```
````

Comment: there is a nearly identical (but now deleted, so invisible to low-rep users) question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239317/error-in-parse-all-in-rstudio-with-knitr ... I wonder if some piece of infrastructure is (probably temporarily) broken?

Comment: aargh I have the same. It started when I updated the knitr package. If only I had read your question before... Is there a way to revert the updates?

Comment: My guess is your version of the evaluate package is too old. Please see FAQ1: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md

Comment: Had the same issue, and it fixed it by updating the evaluate package.

Comment: Same for me, upgraded evaluate from version 0.8 to version 0.9 and the problem went away.

Comment: for some reason I had to install evaluate with `install.packages("evaluate",type = "binary")` to get it to work.

Answer (score 17):

After seeing the same error, the following (updating evaluate package) helped me

```
install.packages("evaluate")
```

Evaluate is used by knitr. Here is a link to CRAN about evaluate:
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/evaluate/index.html

My R version is 3.2.4. There is no need to do any complicated re-installs. Try this first.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, Vincent is right. You seem to have updated your `knitr` package to version 1.13 in the last days. This version only runs under the new `R` version 3.3.0 (also released a couple days ago).

You have two options:

1. Update `R` to version 3.3.0
2. Revert your `knitr` installation to version 1.12 using the following code:

   ```
   packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/knitr/knitr_1.12.tar.gz"
   install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
   ```

Comment: Interestingly, I had a similar problem as the OP had, in that I was getting a warning that `parse_all()` could not be found.  I was using a brand-new install of `R (3.3.0)` and the `knitr (1.13)` package.  However, in trying to make the code work (which worked on a previous machine with an older version of `R` and `knitr`),  I reverted `knitr` to version 1.12 and things are working without issue now.  Do you know of any existing issues with `knitr` and `R 3.3.0`?

Comment: Hey @Steven, no I don't. I have to admit that I have not updated to `R (3.3.0)` yet and instead chose option #2 from above. Have you updated RStudio, too?

Comment: I did.  I updated my entire machine yesterday.  I opened up an [issue on the `knitr` github page just in case](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1214).

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same exact problem, hence I came up with this page. Based on the suggestions, I installed R version 3.3.0, and uninstalled 3.2.4. I re-installed the packages. However, fread function stopped working. I read that it might be related to dll's being messed up etc. Then I completely uninstalled R, and Rstudio. I also deleted the library folder where the packages are installed. Re-installed R, then Rstudio (latest version  0.99.902), then the packages. Now everything is working fine.