# R Markdown error

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, knitr

I am trying to create an R markdown file but when I do I get the following error:

```
Line 2:
Error in .Call(C_str Sub_replacement, str, from, to, NULL, value) :
Incorrect number of arguments (5), expecting 6 for 'C_str Sub Replacement'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... indir -> inline exec -> <Anonymous> -> str_sub<- -> .Call
```

I have tried searching the internet and can not find an answer to this specific error. I am running R-3.3.0 and using R Studio.

I have updated the packages - knitr, markdown and yaml.

The following is my set up:

````
---
title: "Setting up a DQASS PC"
author: "DKMillington"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
  css: mystyle.css
toc: true
number_sections: true
---

  ```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE, comment = "#>")
library(dqass)
```
````

Thank you for your time in advance.

Dale

Comment: I can neither reproduce the error (it compiles fine, lacking the package) nor find `dqass` to install and test. Perhaps the problem is with the package itself and not the Rmd. Can you run `library(dqass)` on the console without error?

Comment: Hello r2evans and thank you for your reply. Yes the dqass package loads correctly but I should have mentioned the dqass package is job specific and unfortunately private. Other staff members are managing to run markdown files okay with this package loaded so I don't think that is where the issue lies. Is downloading the 'yaml', 'knitr' and 'markdown' packages via the install.packages() command adequate? I am also running a 64-bit OS if this makes a difference - Dale

Comment: Alright. Other questions (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241578/getting-a-parser-all-error-in-r-when-using-knitr-for-converting-a-basic-rmd-file/37820042#37820042) have discussed recent changes to `knitr` and the respective R version, so it's possible that this is beyond the versions I have (R-3.2.5 and knitr-1.12.3). In the other question, there was a suggestion to revert to knitr-1.12, perhaps that can shed some light on the problem?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately I am still receiving the same error. I have also tried using an older version of R and this has not helped.   I will keep looking for an answer and let you know if I am lucky enough to find it :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to reinstall the **stringi** package.

Comment: @ Yihui - Yes this has worked, thank you very much!