# unused arguments (filename, stop_on_error !=2) when try to publish interactive documents in shinyapp.io

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to publish an interactive document (R markdown) with shiny components in shinyapp.io. The app runs locally without any errors,and also during the deployment process no errors seem to appear (after click "publish" button on RStudio). However, everytime I try to publish the doc, the opened browser shows this message: **unused arguments (filename, stop_on_error !=2)**.

I'm currently using google chrome as browser, but I tried to open the app through Internet Explorer (If this info is useful)

I already tried a few solutions, for example, set the working directory to the app directory, and strip off any library that is not in use...But these alternatives failed.

Here is the code of my app:

#### App-2.Rmd

First chunck:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
title: "App_2"
author: "Ingrid XXX"
date: "29 de julho de 2016"
--- 
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

```{r, echo=FALSE}

dados <- read.csv("b_d.csv",header = T,na.strings = c("(null)"),encoding =    "UTF-8" )
dados<- dados[,1:31]


dados$DATA.FATO <- parse_date_time(dados$DATA.FATO, c('dmY', 'dmy'))
dados$DATA.FATO <- as.Date(dados$DATA.FATO)

```
````

Second chunck:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$datas <- renderUI({

  dateRangeInput("date", "Selecione a faixa de datas:", start="2012-01-01", end="2012-12-31", 
               min="2012-01-01", max="2012-12-31", format="dd-mm-yyyy", separator = "-")
  })


  date1=reactive({as.character(input$date[1])})
  date2=reactive({as.character(input$date[2])})

  dados2=reactive({

    subset(dados, DATA.FATO >= date1() & DATA.FATO <= date2())

  })

  dat <- reactive({

    ocorrencias_DIA <- dados2()%>%
     group_by(DATA.FATO)%>%
     summarise(count=n())

   })


  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
  
   ggplot(dat(),aes(x=DATA.FATO,y=count))+geom_line()+geom_smooth()

   })

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Média de Ocorrências ano 2012"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
              
     uiOutput("datas")
  
    ),

  mainPanel(
  
  
    plotOutput(outputId="main_plot"))

   )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```
````

Can anyone indicate what is the cause and the proper solution to this problem?

Any help would be very appreaciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved through update of package "evaluate" v.0.8 to v.0.9. It was possible through tips given in: [getting a parser_all error in R when using knitr for converting a basic Rmd file into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241578/getting-a-parser-all-error-in-r-when-using-knitr-for-converting-a-basic-rmd-file)