# R markdown error in evaluate_call(...) when knitting any Rmd file

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I can no longer knit any of my Rmd files to PDF or Html. It's the same error message every time:

> Line 9 Error in evaluate_call(expr, parsed$src[[i]], envir = envir,
>   enclos=enclos, : unused argument (include_timing = include_timing)
>   Calls: ... call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> evalute ->
>   evalute_call Execution halted

Line 9 is an auto-generated line when opening a new R markdown file:

`{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`

I've tried deleting it, changing `TRUE` to `FALSE`, and deleting part of it. It gives me the same error message stopped on the same line.

Comment: you may try `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE)`

Comment: This problem does not appear on Rstudio 1.00.12 and the dev version of bookdown. After I upgrade to Rstudio 1.00.44 and the released version of bookdown 0.1, it occurs.

Comment: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE)` fixed the error for me

Comment: I don't understand how turning off the evaluation can be a solution, isn't having the expressions evaluated the point of including R code?

Answer (score 9):

If you are still receiving the same error Yihui, from the same linked answer above says to update the `evaluate` package. When I updated, the error stopped. I am currently running 3.3.1.

Yihui offered guidance in the knitr FAQ1 here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem when I tried to update `knitr` to version 1.13 or 1.14. I get the same error if I try to knit with an `R` version 3.2.x or 3.3.x. I suggest reverting to `knitr` version 1.12 using the below. I don't get the above error with 1.12.

`packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/knitr/knitr_1.12.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")`

Taken from this answer: [getting a parser_all error in R when using knitr for converting a basic Rmd file into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241578/getting-a-parser-all-error-in-r-when-using-knitr-for-converting-a-basic-rmd-file). Still unsure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and after hours of arguing with my code i just updated all my packages in R and that fixed it! So happy. I was having the issue even with the r markdown test document that r studio creates automatically, but this resolved it.

Comment: Actually, this comment is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try install the development version from XRAN as suggested in https://github.com/yihui/knitr.

```
# update all existing packages first
update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.org')
install.packages('knitr', repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.org'))
```

I had met the same problem, and tried several approaches.

1. downgrade knitr version to 1.12. It works, but *R Notebook*
   function will not be supported
2. update *evaluate* package. Unfortunately it does not
   solve the problem.
3. re-install software (Rstudio, pandoc, MikTex).
   Not work either
4. install a development version as mentioned above.
   It works at last!

BTW. Here is my environment info.

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Rstudio Version 1.0.44
```

The root-cause of the issue is not clear to me up to now. After I installed a preview version of Rstudio for *R Notebook* trial. It worked very well at the beginning. However after I installed *MikTex* for PDF output. The problem came out.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to knitr defining its default "evaluate" hook as:

```
.default.hooks = list(
  # ...
  evaluate = evaluate::evaluate
  # ...
)
```

The knitr package was first installed while evaluate-1.0 (or later) was available. These versions had `evaluate::evaluate` taking an optional `include_timing` argument. The knitr hook code effectively cached the implementation of `evaluate::evaluate` as it was installed+compiled.

At some later point, evaluate-0.9 (or earlier) was installed on the system. You could no longer knit documents because knitr was still using its cached evaluate-0.10 version of `evaluate::evaluate` -- it attempted to pass the `include_timing` argument to `evaluate::evaluate_call`. This is the evaluate-0.9 version of `evaluate::evaluate_call` and does not expect the `include_timing` argument. Kaboom. The error.

This was reported (and now fixed) here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1441

If you do not wish to update knitr, you have a couple of choices for workarounds:

1. Register the correct version of `evaluate::evaluate` as the knitr "evaluate" hook:

   ```
   knitr::knit_hooks$set(evaluate = evaluate::evaluate)
   ```
2. Force the reinstallation of whatever version of knitr you are using (with `devtools::install_github` or some other method).