# R evaluate_call() error

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

When I run my own rmd script I got an error. I've tried to create a whole new rmd file, however it keeps giving me the same error. This new .rmd file is the basic start of a .rmd file. So:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# More of the code isn't needed to create the error.
````

If only the chunk is ran the following is shown in the console:

[image: Run chunk]

If the knit to word is used the following error is given:

[image: error]

my versions:
knitr 1.14, rmarkdown 1.1

**My question:** What do I have to change in order to get the code running? Or isn't this my fault and is this a bug?

Comment: Try some of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241578/getting-a-parser-all-error-in-r-when-using-knitr-for-converting-a-basic-rmd-file), perhaps? Try updating the `evaluate` package.

Comment: Works fine for me on an updated machine, so I cannot reproduce your error. As @sebastian-c said, update the `evaluate` package (should be version 0.10). I close your question as a duplicate of the previous one where the answer was given.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :)